# Gravity Forms, insert entry via $.post

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins, gravity

I was wondering if anyone knew if there is a hook for gravity forms to $.post serialised form data so Gravity Forms can handle it and insert it into the database.

I was digging around the code and couldn't find how Gravity Forms itself inserts data as the URL action of the form seems just to be the permalink of the page.

I couldn't find a hook either where I could use the WordPress Ajax api to hook into a gravity forms insert entry sort of function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be what I'm looking for is this:
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/API_Functions#add_entry